# space of vector fields is infinite dimensional for a smooth embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $\geq 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth embedded submanfold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If the dimension of $\Sigma$ is at least one, then Vec$(\Sigma)$ is an infinite-dimesional vector space.

The solution of my professor, which I have been trying to understand for hours, says:

Let $v_{(n)} := x_1^n \frac{1}{\partial x_1}$. Then, suppose $\sum_{j=1}^N c_j v_j = 0$, therefore $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j x^j \partial _j = 0$. But then $f=c_j x^j$ is the zero-function on $\mathbb{R}^N$ therefore all $c_j$ are zero.

My guesses: we identified Vec$(\Sigma)$ with all smooth mappings $v: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^n$, which fulfilled $v(x) \cdot \nabla f (x)=0$, where $\Sigma$ is the presage of a regular value of the function $f$. For example for the 2-sphere, $f(x,y,z)= x^2 +y^2+z^2 = 1$ that would mean, that these are all mappings which give

$$
2 \begin{bmatrix} v_1(x,y,z) \\
v_2(x,y,z) \\
v_3(x,y,z)
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now since $v$ is a smooth map from $\Sigma$ to the tangent bundle $T \Sigma$, I guess I can describe it in the basis of the tangent space, and I guess he somehow did that (?), however, I still don't understand what he is doing and I also think he sometimes uses Einstein-summation but sometimes not in this proof, so that is very confusing. I appreciate any help!

Comment: It's rather about the linear independency of the monomial functions $x\mapsto x^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! But shouldn't it then read sth like $v_n = x_1^n v$, therefore $0=\sum_{n=1}^N c_n v_n = \left( \sum_{n=1}^N c_n x_1^n \right) v$, therefore $\sum_{n=1}^N c_n x_1^n = 0$ and so the $c_n$'s? If so, I do not understand why this first $v$ exists..

Comment: In his proof, I don't see why $v_{(n)} = x^1  \frac{1}{\partial x_^1}$ is even a vector field, because it doesn't fulfil the above characterisation.